# Problem with model view controll in Windows application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

ok. I have a question about use my data model in UI. problem is with windows forms.
In the presentation tier, I set my data model equals to their relevant texboxes, lables.. etc. but all the time my data model being change, I have to manually update the UI also. Same thing happens again when I change some value in textBox or anything else in UI, I have to update manually my data Model also.

Aren't there a way, a better way to set this to be happened automatically ? When I change data Model, UI also be changed accordingly? also When I change values in UI, data Model also be updated automatically??

Regards,

-Kushan-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Data Binding](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html) within Windows Forms to achieve what you are going after. There are a varying number of samples [here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_databinding.html).

The sample below is a single `Form` with two `TextBox` (textBox1, textBox2) controls and one `Button` (button1) on it. If you put a new name in textbox2 and clicked button1 it will set the property on the `Person.FirstName` property which will propagate to textBox1 since it has been data bound as seen in the ctor of `Form1`.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Person _person = new Person();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", _person, "FirstName"));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _person.FirstName = textBox2.Text;
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private String _firstName = "Aaron";
        public String FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName;
            }
            set 
            {
                _firstName = value;
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if(handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion
    }

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx
```

Comment: thanks for the response. can you please gimme some code examples of DataBinding ? jst a very small example including key points?. I've tried this before. but still couldn't get it to use as i want.

Comment: @Kushan Added sample plus another link to a number of varying samples across the varying controls; if you are not tied to Windows Forms, now is a good time to jump ship to WPF as you will gain a wealth of functionality within the binding arena.

Comment: great.... thank you Aaron. this is the thing I need. thank you again for your effort.